# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary

Tags: java, bigdecimal

when i try to get the longValueExact() :

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(432.900).divide(new BigDecimal(1), 2, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println(bigDecimal.longValueExact());

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Rounding necessary
    at java.math.BigDecimal.commonNeedIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4151)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.needIncrement(BigDecimal.java:4207)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.divideAndRound(BigDecimal.java:4115)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(BigDecimal.java:2455)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.longValueExact(BigDecimal.java:3093)
    at com.tessi.bmd.specific.actil.utils.ActilUtils.main(ActilUtils.java:1281)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's [intended and documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValueExact()) if the value cannot be exactly represented by a `long`. Not sure what your issue is; if you are fine with rounding just use `longValue` instead of `longValueExact`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `new BigDecimal(432.900)`

This is a bad idea. `432.900` is a double literal and is therefore highly unlikely to actually represent `432.900`. You're using BigDecimal, so presumably you know that there are only at most 2^64 numbers in existence that are exactly representable by a `double`. 432.900 is not one of them. Do not use this constructor - it has warnings all over it. Use `new BigDecimal("432.9")`.

> `.divide(new BigDecimal(1),`

Okay, divide by 1, not going to do anything. Also, use `BigDecimal.ONE` for this.

The value is still 432.899999999999434 or whatnot.

> `System.out.println(bigDecimal.longValueExact());`

Of course that doesn't work - a long value can only hold integral values, and 432.9 (or something close to that) isn't.

Are you perhaps thinking that `432.900` is just a way of writing `432900` that is more readable to humans from certain locales where `.` is used as thousands separator?

`.` is the decimals separator. `432.900` is a double literal that represents the nearest representable double to the number 432 + 9/10ths. If that's your intend, remove the `.` - if you want to create some horizontal space for the yes, use `_` which is legal in number literals and meaningless.

If that's not your problem and you really want `432.9` as an exact long - I guess, go back to square one and start learning java. Soon (as in, within a day or two, no doubt) you'll hit the part of the tutorial that explains the primitive data types. Pay extra attention to this section.

Comment: @l4mpi The specific unclear aspect (Was `432.900` an attempt at using a thousands separator, or an attempt to write 432 plus 9/10ths) is very specific. If that is a reason to close the question, 99 out of 100 questions on SO should be closed for being unclear.

Comment: No, that's just your charitable interpretation of OPs question; it's not clear if that's the issue, or if OP does not understand the error message, or needs to read up on the java datatypes (which you've alluded to in your own answer), or if it's something else entirely. Also, I totally agree that most questions on SO should be closed.

Comment: _Also, I totally agree that most questions on SO should be closed._ not what I said, and I don't think fly-by commenting answers to brigade this exotic opinion is a good use of SO.  _No, that's just your charitable interpretation of OPs question_ Who made you the boss of determining if an interpretation is 'charitable' versus 'fair'? __Every answer__ on SO makes assumptions.

Comment: Ok, let me restate that. Your answer includes a paragraph that questions if OP even knows the basics of the java language (which some people might even interpret to violate the "be nice" policy). Sentences such as "go back to square one and start learning java" are IMO a reflection of the abyssimal quality of OPs question. If the question makes you feel like OP might not even understand the very basics of programming such as basic datatypes, the best thing to do is to not answer it, but vote to close it and optionally post a comment asking for clarification.

Comment: @l4mpi That's a fair point. I was assuming (hoping?) it was the former issue, that OP confused `.` for `_`.

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal behavior because the value you want to display as a long has decimal part (432.89, not 432.90 due to instatiating BigDecimal from a double) so is not an interger number. From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#longValueExact--):

> Converts this BigDecimal to a long, checking for lost information. If
> this BigDecimal has a nonzero fractional part or is out of the
> possible range for a long result then an ArithmeticException is
> thrown.